# django pandas pd.ExcelFile() throws error no such file

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas, python-3.5

I am using the pynthon3 and Django framework and wanted to read the excel file with the help of pandas, my excel file is present at the level of view file directory.
I am doing the following code snap for reading the file, but its throw the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'formate.xlsx'"

`df = pd.ExcelFile("formate.xlsx", sheetname=sname)`

What should I do?

Comment: try to put it to the project root directory, and best way to generate full path to you file, based on django conf `basedir`